# JComboBox Select and Item and Based off of the selection display a new list

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I have the following code so that based off of the user selection a list is displayed:

```
    private class SheepTypeListHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox<String> cb = (JComboBox<String>)(e.getSource());
        if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals(sheepType[0])) {
            for (String item : eweClass )
            sheepClassCB.addItem(item);
        }
        else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals(sheepType[1])) {
            for (String item : ramClass )
                sheepClassCB.addItem(item);
            for (String item : weight3 )
                weightCB.addItem(item);
        }
        else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals(sheepType[2])) {
            for (String item : lambClass )
                sheepClassCB.addItem(item);
        }
    }
    } //End SheepTypeListHandler class
```

Currently, depending on what you select a new list does pop up. However, if you change your mind and select a new item, instead of overriding what is there it just adds the new list to the bottom of the first list.

For example:
If the user selects sheepType[2] then the following list appears:

```
Finishing
Early-weaned
```

Now if they change their mind and choose sheepType[0] instead of this list:

```
Maintenance
Nonlactating, first 15 weeks gestation
Last 6 wks gestation OR Last 8 wks lactation suckling singles
First 8 wks lactation suckling singles OR last 8 wks lactation suckling twins
First 8 weeks lactation suckling twins
Replacement lambs and yearlings
```

I get this:

```
Finishing
Early-weaned
Maintenance
Nonlactating, first 15 weeks gestation
Last 6 wks gestation OR Last 8 wks lactation suckling singles
First 8 wks lactation suckling singles OR last 8 wks lactation suckling twins
First 8 weeks lactation suckling twins
Replacement lambs and yearlings
```

How do I alter my current code to override when a new selection is made instead of just adding to the list?
Thanks!

UPDATE:
With part of my code edited to the following:

```
private class SheepTypeListHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sheepClassCB.removeAllItems(); 
        if (sheepListCB.getSelectedItem().equals(sheepType[0])) {
            //sheepClassCB.removeAllItems(); //This did not work
            for (String item : eweClass ){
                sheepClassCB.addItem(item);
            }
        }
        else if (sheepListCB.getSelectedItem().equals(sheepType[1])) {
            for (String item : ramClass )
                sheepClassCB.addItem(item);
            for (String item : weight3 )
                weightCB.addItem(item);
        }
        else if (sheepListCB.getSelectedItem().equals(sheepType[2])) {
            for (String item : lambClass )
                sheepClassCB.addItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now The first time I choose an item out of the list it works. But if I reselect a different item it shows an empty list.

Comment: So clear the list before adding data to it. Look at the API for your component to see if it has a method for this. Otherwise look at the API for the model of your component to see what the method is.

Comment: What type is `sheepClassCB`?

Comment: `sheepClassCB` is a JComboBox generated from a String Array List: `JComboBox<String> sheepListCB = new JComboBox<>(sheepType);`

Comment: See my answer and find where the difference is between my working code and yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the line `sheepClassCB.removeAllItems()`. I made a simple example based on your code:

```
public class ListEmpty extends JFrame {

    JComboBox<String> changingCB = new JComboBox<>();
    JComboBox<String> unchangingCB = new JComboBox<>();

    String[] numbers = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
    String[] letters = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] symbols = new String[] {"!", "@", "#"};

    ListEmpty() {

        unchangingCB.addItem("Numbers");
        unchangingCB.addItem("Letters");
        unchangingCB.addItem("Symbols");
        unchangingCB.addActionListener(new SheepTypeListHandler());

        getContentPane().add(unchangingCB, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        getContentPane().add(changingCB, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class SheepTypeListHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            changingCB.removeAllItems(); // Compare with removing this line.
            if (unchangingCB.getSelectedItem().equals("Numbers")) {
                for (String item : numbers)
                    changingCB.addItem(item);
            } else if (unchangingCB.getSelectedItem().equals("Letters")) {
                for (String item : letters)
                    changingCB.addItem(item);
            } else if (unchangingCB.getSelectedItem().equals("Symbols")) {
                for (String item : symbols)
                    changingCB.addItem(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ListEmpty();
    }
}
```

You may want to consider a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if-else` statements.

Comment: The above answer works but I found in the case of multiple ComboBoxes that work based off of different selections made in another ComboBox you also need to turn off the ActionListener before performing an action on one and then turn it back on after the action is complete. Otherwise it still functions incorrectly.

Comment: @tinkerton101 Without seeing a code example of what "*multiple ComboBoxes that work based off of different selections made in another ComboBox*" means, I can't give a proper response. My answer above is for your initial question "*How do I alter my current code to override when a new selection is made instead of just adding to the list?*".

Comment: the issue is resolved. Adding your code fixed the initial problem and then adding my extra bit works in the case of multiple ComboBoxes that must interact with one another.

Comment: @tinkerton101 Alright, but turning on and off `ActionListener`s usually means that something went wrong in the design. Whatever works for you, though.